# listen JavaScript data in android

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying get data from JavaScript file in android but I cannot catch data which coming from inside method in JavaScript, I shared below JS File and data inside methods Which I want to catch in android.I listen like bottom but I cannot get data from JS

this returns message webPageOpen and WebPageClose and data(Type and Url) how can I listen it in android

```
playWebPageWidget:function(url, status){
    var privateDataResponseMessage = {};
    privateDataResponseMessage.Type =status==1? 'WebPageOpen':'WebPageClose';
    privateDataResponseMessage.Url = url;
    window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(privateDataResponseMessage));
},
```

android codes

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    public WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playWebPageWidget(String toast,String url) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
    WebView browser = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.webView);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/index.html");
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in `WebView`, you need to set up a JavaScript interface.

Read: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript

EDIT: If you want to show a toast from the JS thread. Do this:

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

Please try this and confirm that it works.

Comment: I am edited code at above but it doesn't show Toast message

Comment: This is because the toast is being called from the JS thread. I will edit my answer for you.